# Game only functions at 800 fps

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I had a problem in my program, and at first I thought it was related to coroutines. Every script that featured a coroutine worked slower in it's entirety. I later discovered this was the case because of a difference in FPS. In the editor, the FPS was 800, while it was 60 in the build. When I changed the code, so it would be 800 in both, everything worked fine.

This fixed everything, but this feels like a weird solution. It's a very simple project, so I don't mind for now, but I'd still like to know what's going on. Any ideas?

```
public IEnumerator BeInvincible()
{
    
   isInvincible = true;
    for (float i = 0; i < invistime; i += invistimedelta)
    {
        // Alternate between 0 and 1 scale to simulate flashing
        if (sprite.color == new Color(1, 1, 1, 1))
        {
            sprite.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            sprite.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(invistimedelta);
    }
    sprite.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    isInvincible = false;
    

}
```

I use fixedupdate for movement, and update for inputs. When I put inputs in fixedupdate (50 FPS), the game reacts the bad way, even when the game runs in base 800 fps.

Comment: `the game reacts the bad way` I don't know what this means.

Comment: There isn’t enough info to answer your questions. One coroutine isn’t enough

Answer (score 2):

Bad in what way?

In any case, if there is a problem at the time of code execution
Or a direct delay in performance, most likely the problem is from here

```
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(invistimedelta);
```

The execution of a coroutine can be paused at any point using the yield statement. When a yield statement is used, the coroutine pauses execution and automatically resumes at the next frame. See the [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) documentation for more details.

And also you can review [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)